# angular 2 get data from rest server is zero length - how to debug?

Tags: angular

Using the Heroes tutorial on the Angular 2 website. I have set up the heroService to use a rest service from tomcat. Using curl produces the correct result

```
C:\Temp\curl>curl http://centos7-ansible:8080/heroes/heroes
[{"id":1,"name":"Mr. Nice"},{"id":2,"name":"Narco"},{"id":3,"name":"Bombasto"},{"id":4,"name":"Celeritas"},{"id":5,"name":"Magneta"},{"id":6,"name":"RubberMan"},{"id":7,"name":"Dynama"},{"id":8,"name":"Dr IQ"},{"id":9,"name":"Magma"},{"id":10,"name":"Tornado"}]
```

So in the hero.service.ts,

```
private heroesUrl = 'http://centos7-ansible:8080/heroes/heroes';  // URL to web api
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
               .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

In the calling component,

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log("about to get data");   
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(4, 8));
        console.log("returned from getting data");
        console.log(length of array is " + this.heroes.length );
  }
```

Looking at the console I get

```
about to get data 
GET http://centos7-ansible:8080/heroes/heroes   200 OK  43ms     
returned from getting data 
length of array is 0
```

So it works from curl but within Angular does not.

Also, looking at the access log in Tomcat, the same log message is for both curl and angular access.

```
"GET /heroes/heroes HTTP/1.1" 200 273
"GET /heroes/heroes HTTP/1.1" 200 273
```

Is the "273" the length of data returned? Which would suggest the data is there but is not being put in the Hero array?
Is my heroesUrl correct?
Within console, I get

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: e is undefined
```

What does this mean? What is "e"?
How do I go about debugging this as the console gives the code lines as part of a bundle.js.

Comment: There is no `data` in your json.

Comment: Is this due to how I have switched from using inMemoryDbService to using an external service?

Answer (score 1):

Can you replace the following line

```
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(4, 8));
```

with

```
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => { this.heroes = heroes.slice(4, 8);  console.log(length of array is " + this.heroes.length ); });
```

and check if the correct length is printed in the console now?

Comment: Kevin, made change as you suggested. The log message does not appear in the console. The log message before the getHeroes() call is displayed but not length of array. As the web page is not showing any data I presume that the array length of zero is correct.